# White space beside content when I reduce the screen size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am studying CSS and creating a responsive web page. I have started working in a media query. When I maximize the screen, all works as expected, but when I reduce its size, the content that does not fit in the viewport is hidden, and a white space stays in its place. That space can be seen scrolling the screen to side. Why is that space appearing instead the rest of the content? I also don't understand why my content doesn't fit in the screen, because I am using percentage values to elements' width. My code is below:

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Doppio+One|Open+Sans&display=swap');
html, body, *, *::before, *::after {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body{
 width: 99.13vw;
}
body{
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 margin: 0;
}
h2, h3{
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
a{
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: 0.2s linear;
}
header{
 background-color: rgb(93, 158, 76);
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 width: 100%;
}
header img{
 width: 45px;
}
header h1{
 font-family: 'Doppio One', cursive;
 margin-left: 10px;
 color: rgb(214, 245, 210);
}
nav ul{
 display: flex;
 list-style: none;
}
nav ul li a{
 margin-left: 55px;
}
nav a{
 color: rgb(230, 245, 229);
 font-size: 17px;
}
nav a:hover{
 background-color: rgb(143, 182, 135);
 padding: 10px 15px;
 margin: 0 -15px 0 40px;
}
nav img{
 display: none;
 width: 30px;
 height: 35px;
}
#firstsection{
 background-image: url(Images/coffee-3289259_1280.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 height: 900px;
 position: relative;
}
#firstsection div{
 margin-top: 0;
 position: absolute;
 left: 100px;
 top: 150px;
 color: rgb(47, 119, 27);
 text-align: center;
}
#firstsection h1{
 margin-bottom: 45px;
}
#firstsection div a{
 font-weight: bold;
 border: 2px solid rgb(47, 119, 27);
 padding: 13px 30px;
 font-size: 16.5px;
 color: rgb(47, 119, 27);
}
#firstsection div a:hover{
 color: rgb(133, 163, 131);
 border: 2px solid rgb(133, 163, 131);
}
#textboxes{
 display: flex;
 margin-top: 50px;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#textboxes div{
 text-align: center;
 margin: 15px 60px;
 border: 2px solid rgb(93, 158, 76);
 padding: 30px 30px;
 width: 27%;
}
#middlesection img:first-of-type{
 width: 55px;
}
#middlesection h2{
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
}
#lastsection{
 text-align: center;
}
#lastsection img{
 width: 30%;
 margin: 100px auto 0px;
}
#lastsection div{
 position: relative;
 bottom: 450px;
}
#lastsection div a:visited{
 color: blue;
}
footer{
 background-color: rgb(93, 158, 76);
 padding: 15px;
 color: rgb(214, 245, 210);
 font-size: 14px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
footer img{
 height: 35px;
 width: 35px;
 margin-right: 15px;
}
footer div{
 text-align: center;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
 #textboxes div{
  width: 100%;
 }
 #lastsection img{
  width: 85%;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Finances | Manage your money easily</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
 <meta content="Control you spending and manage your money easily. Your finances by the short hairs." name="description">
 <meta content="Bruno M. B. Sdoukos" name="author">
 <meta content="finances, managing money, spending control" name="keywords">
 <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <a href="index.html"><img src="Images/icons8-fund-accounting-80.png"></a> <a href="index.html">
  <h1>Finances</h1></a>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li>
     <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Contact us</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Register</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Login</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
 <main>
  <section id="firstsection">
   <div>
    <h1>Manage your money easily, anywhere, anytime.</h1><a href="#">Get started</a>
   </div>
  </section>
  <section id="middlesection">
   <div id="textboxes">
    <div>
     <img src="Images/icons8-increase-64.png">
     <h3>Concrete data</h3>
     <p>Simple but concrete data that are the answer to all the quesions about your current money, spending and.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
     <img src="Images/icons8-navigation-toolbar-left-filled-50%20(1).png">
     <h3>Easy interface</h3>
     <p>An interface easy to use, made to you who want to manage your money faster and with no problems.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
     <img src="Images/icons8-natural-user-interface-2-filled-50.png">
     <h3>Fast access</h3>
     <p>No complications that make you lose time. Just some clicks and done, you are in Finances, with all you need.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>
  <section id="lastsection">
   <img src="Images/board-1362851_1280.png">
   <div>
    <h2>Register now and enjoy<br>
    the best of Finances.</h2><a href="#">Create an account</a>
   </div>
  </section>
 </main>
 <footer>
  <img src="Images/icons8-fund-accounting-80.png">
  <div>
   <p>A work of Bruno Sdoukos.</p>
  </div>
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to the question, but if you want it to be truly responsive, never use absolute units such as "px".  Instead use relative units such as "em", and "%".  And if it _is_ truly responsive, you'll never need @media tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's not hidden. The links in the header just happen to have a color that's close enough to white that the contrast is really low. They're overflowing the right side of the header when the header's content is wider than the viewport.

The simplest solution would be to give `flex-wrap:wrap` to `header`, but I recommend using a media query to override the `display:flex` instead (for better backwards compatibility).

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Doppio+One|Open+Sans&display=swap');
html,
body,
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 99.13vw;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

h2,
h3 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
}

header {
  background-color: rgb(93, 158, 76);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

@media all and (max-width:56em) {
  header {
    display: block;
  }
  header>a,
  header>nav {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

header img {
  width: 45px;
}

header h1 {
  font-family: 'Doppio One', cursive;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: rgb(214, 245, 210);
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  margin-left: 55px;
}

nav a {
  color: rgb(230, 245, 229);
  font-size: 17px;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(143, 182, 135);
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 0 -15px 0 40px;
}

nav img {
  display: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 35px;
}

#firstsection {
  background-image: url(Images/coffee-3289259_1280.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 900px;
  position: relative;
}

#firstsection div {
  margin-top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 150px;
  color: rgb(47, 119, 27);
  text-align: center;
}

#firstsection h1 {
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}

#firstsection div a {
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px solid rgb(47, 119, 27);
  padding: 13px 30px;
  font-size: 16.5px;
  color: rgb(47, 119, 27);
}

#firstsection div a:hover {
  color: rgb(133, 163, 131);
  border: 2px solid rgb(133, 163, 131);
}

#textboxes {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 50px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#textboxes div {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 15px 60px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(93, 158, 76);
  padding: 30px 30px;
  width: 27%;
}

#middlesection img:first-of-type {
  width: 55px;
}

#middlesection h2 {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#lastsection {
  text-align: center;
}

#lastsection img {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 100px auto 0px;
}

#lastsection div {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 450px;
}

#lastsection div a:visited {
  color: blue;
}

footer {
  background-color: rgb(93, 158, 76);
  padding: 15px;
  color: rgb(214, 245, 210);
  font-size: 14px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

footer img {
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

footer div {
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #textboxes div {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #lastsection img {
    width: 85%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Finances | Manage your money easily</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
  <meta content="Control you spending and manage your money easily. Your finances by the short hairs." name="description">
  <meta content="Bruno M. B. Sdoukos" name="author">
  <meta content="finances, managing money, spending control" name="keywords">
  <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <a href="index.html"><img src="Images/icons8-fund-accounting-80.png"></a>
    <a href="index.html">
      <h1>Finances</h1>
    </a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Contact us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Register</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Login</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section id="firstsection">
      <div>
        <h1>Manage your money easily, anywhere, anytime.</h1><a href="#">Get started</a>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="middlesection">
      <div id="textboxes">
        <div>
          <img src="Images/icons8-increase-64.png">
          <h3>Concrete data</h3>
          <p>Simple but concrete data that are the answer to all the quesions about your current money, spending and.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="Images/icons8-navigation-toolbar-left-filled-50%20(1).png">
          <h3>Easy interface</h3>
          <p>An interface easy to use, made to you who want to manage your money faster and with no problems.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="Images/icons8-natural-user-interface-2-filled-50.png">
          <h3>Fast access</h3>
          <p>No complications that make you lose time. Just some clicks and done, you are in Finances, with all you need.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="lastsection">
      <img src="Images/board-1362851_1280.png">
      <div>
        <h2>Register now and enjoy<br> the best of Finances.</h2><a href="#">Create an account</a>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <img src="Images/icons8-fund-accounting-80.png">
    <div>
      <p>A work of Bruno Sdoukos.</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```